# хранение java.util.Date в mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Сохраняю сущность в бд с датой

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date=new Date();
```

, использую связку jpa+hibernate, когда достаю сущность из бд, то время в дате обнуляется - `00:00:00`. Почему так, как с этим бороться и если всё печально, что посоветуете использовать вместо `util.Date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что используете `TemporalType.DATE`, который указывает, что работаете только с датой без времени. Используйте дату+время, то есть `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`.

A в целом рекомендую переходить на Java 8 и использовать классы `LocalDateTime` и `ZonedDateTime`. В последних версиях `Hibernate` появилась их полная поддержка.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте вместо `DATE` - `TIMESTAMP`, и время пропадать не будет.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateTime;
```